# How to secure a template engine in PHP from injection

Tags: php, security, templates

I am currently trying to create a simple template engine in PHP. The main thing I care about is security, however template tutorials do not. Lets say I have a database table with a username and his description. The user can type whatever he wants there.

My guess would be to use htmlspecialchars() function, to prevent javascript and html injection. But what about 'template code injection'? If my template rule is to replace [@key] to "value", the user can update his description that interferes with my template handler. Should I treat "[", "@", "]" as special characters and replace them with their ascii code when using my set method?

template.php:

```
class Template {
    protected $file;
    protected $values = array();

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->values[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function output() {
        if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
            return "Error loading template file ($this->file).";
        }
        $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

        foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
            $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
            $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

example.tpl:

Username: [@name]
About me: [@info]

index.php:

```
include 'template.php';
$page = new Template('example.tpl');
$page->set('info', '[@name][@name][@name]I just injected some code.');
$page->set('name', 'Tom');
echo $page->output();
```

This would display:

Username: Tom
About me: TomTomTomI just injected some code.

The code I used is based on:

http://www.broculos.net/2008/03/how-to-make-simple-html-template-engine.html

Comment: If you wouldn’t replace the values subsequently but at all once, this wouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: That would be perfect but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If it's not for learning purposes, please just use well tested and estabilished solution such as Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to search in the unchanged template only once for the known keys:

```
public function output() {
    if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
        return "Error loading template file ($this->file).";
    }
    $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

    $keys = array_keys($this->values);
    $pattern = '$\[@(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keys)) . ')\]$';

    $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {
        return $this->values[$match[1]];
    }, $output);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: 1. It should be "use" instead of "using" (syntax error).
2. You can't pass $this like that (Cannot use $this as lexical variable error), there is a hack for that though. You could add **$self = $this;** right after the pattern and **use $self** instead of **use $this** [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431440/why-can-i-not-use-this-as-a-lexical-variable-in-php-5-5-4
3. It seems to work when I apply those two changes, I'm testing it a bit more at the moment. Please update your answer if you agree with the my first two points.

Comment: @Drikam I wrote it from mind, feel free to edit it when you’ve got the working code.

Comment: @Drikam It seems that `$this` is already visible within the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it and I think this solution is fastest and simplest:

```
foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
    if (strpos($output, "[@$value]") !== FALSE)
      $value = '&#91;'.substr($value,1,-1).'&#93;';
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
}
```

It replaces brackets in value with html entity string if [$value] is in output.

[Used this html entity list](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

For future adopters:
This kind of solution is OK if Template Parser is implemented by loading non-interpeted/non-evaled file (as is OP's case by loading local file using file_get_contents). However, if it's implemented by INCLUDING PHP view, beware that this check won't handle the case when you put some user-modifiable data from database into view directly (without using parser, e.g. `<?=$var;?>`) and then use template parser for this view. In that case, parser has no way to know if these data are part of template structure and this check won't work for them. (I don't know how should this case be handled properly.) Anyhow, I think best practice is to never pass sensitive data to template parser, even if you don't use them in your template. When attacker then tricks parser to eval his custom data, he won't get information he didn't already have. Even better, don't use template parser.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic behind this code, but I can't. Even if this had some typos, I do not think that using 'strpos' (finding the first occurrence) is the way to go. It can occur several times. Maybe what you were trying to say is a bit faster way to do this: $value = str_replace('[', '&#91;', $value); $value = str_replace(']', '&#93;', $value);

Comment: It doesn't matter if it occurs several times. I use strpos to find if there are SOME matches of [$value] in actual template. You can use strstr if you like, it doesn't matter. That condition is there because I wanted to handle in custom way only pairs which are actually used in template. If you replace every bracket, some things WILL stop working for you (e.g. <input name="id[]">). Values which mimic template pairs which are not actually used in current template shouldn't be dangerous, as value for them is generally not set in Template parser. Isn't this working for you?

Comment: Well, I did replace my foreach with yours and it does not work. You gave a valid reason why not to replace all brackets though, I did not think of that. I guess a regex would be best.