# Laravel Cannot use $this Inside Anonymous Function

Tags: php, laravel, anonymous-function

I am using a construct to get request variables only once, since I need to use them in more than one method, I do not want to repeat code.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->labelId   = $request->label;
    $this->statusId  = $request->status;
    $this->monthId   = $request->month;
}
```

This works for my "standard" view, but not for the "label view":

```
public function standard()
{
    $appointments = Appointment::latest('start')->status($this->statusId)->label($this->labelId)->month($this->monthId)->get();

    return view('appointments.index', compact('appointments'));
}

public function label(Request $request)
{
    $appointments = Label::with(['appointments' => function ($query) use ($this->labelId, $this->statusId, $this->monthId) {
        $query->label($this->labelId)->status($this->statusId)->month($this->monthId)->get();
    }])->get();

    return view('appointments.label', compact('appointments'));
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot use $this as lexical variable
```

And the issue is here:

```
function ($query) use ($this->labelId, $this->statusId, $this->monthId)
```

My question is this, can I somehow use the variables anyway in the label method using the construct, or is there maybe a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
$appointments = Label::with(['appointments' => function ($query) use ($this->labelId, $this->statusId, $this->monthId) {
    $query->label($this->labelId)->status($this->statusId)->month($this->monthId)->get();
}])->get();
```

With:

```
$appointments = Label::with(['appointments' => function ($query) {
    $query->label($this->labelId)->status($this->statusId)->month($this->monthId)->get();
}])->get();
```

You [can't pass properties of the current object via `use()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433321/145279), and you can't `use($this)`, however, `$this` is always available in PHP 5.4+.

For this to work properly, you'll need PHP 5.4+. PHP 5.3 and below had a limitation where the local object context cannot be accessed from inside an anonymous function.

> It is not possible to use `$this` from anonymous function before PHP 5.4.0

You could do something like:

```
$instance = $this;
$appointments = Label::with(['appointments' => function ($query) use ($instance) { // ... }
```

But then you couldn't access `private` or `protected` members; it would be seen as a public access. You really need PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot :) Edit: Unfortunately I am getting the same error. But I will look into this.

Comment: No problem. What version of PHP is this?

Comment: Yeah I am using php 5.6 :P And if I use `$instance` it's the same as just using `$request` so :) I need to just think of another solution

Comment: Ok, check out my latest edit. Just take off the `use()` entirely. As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19433321/145279).